# ydn db full text search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ydn-db

Using ydn db full text search i have this code which search all the data related to delhi
with **exact match** and **prefix match**

```
    db_mob_audit.search('mainindex', 'Delhi').done(function (Srchresponse) {
        console.log(Srchresponse);
    });
```

But i want to do search only on **exact match** not on **prefix match** and also i wat ro implement ydn db full text search **implicit logical (and, or)**

Please help me to do this....